# Determine which method is dispatched for a given function call

Tags: methods, julia

Consider the `findfirst` function. I can see which methods are defined for `findfirst` by using `methods`:

```
julia> methods(findfirst)
# 9 methods for generic function "findfirst":
[1] findfirst(A::Union{AbstractString, AbstractArray}) in Base at array.jl:1672
[2] findfirst(p::Union{Base.Fix2{typeof(==),T}, Base.Fix2{typeof(isequal),T}}, r::StepRange{T,S}) where {T, S} in Base at array.jl:1758
[3] findfirst(pred::Base.Fix2{#s66,#s65} where #s65<:Union{Int8, UInt8} where #s66<:Union{typeof(==), typeof(isequal)}, a::Union{Array{Int8,1}, Array{UInt8,1}}) in Base at strings/search.jl:22
[4] findfirst(testf::Function, A::Union{AbstractString, AbstractArray}) in Base at array.jl:1754
[5] findfirst(testf::Function, A) in Base at array.jl:1747
[6] findfirst(pattern::AbstractString, string::AbstractString) in Base at strings/search.jl:104
[7] findfirst(ch::AbstractChar, string::AbstractString) in Base at strings/search.jl:124
[8] findfirst(r::Regex, s::AbstractString) in Base at regex.jl:327
[9] findfirst(A) in Base at array.jl:1663
```

Now suppose I'd like to figure out which of those methods gets dispatched when I call `findfirst(iseven, 1:4)`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`@which`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.@which) macro:

```
julia> @which findfirst(iseven, 1:4)
findfirst(testf::Function, A::Union{AbstractString, AbstractArray}) in Base at array.jl:1754
```

Another example:

```
julia> @which length(1:7)
length(r::AbstractUnitRange{T}) where T<:Union{Int128, Int64} in Base at range.jl:542

julia> @which length("hello world")
length(s::String) in Base at strings/string.jl:259
```

**Edit:**

As @giordano points out in the comments, you can use

```
@less findfirst(iseven, 1:4)
```

or

```
@edit findfirst(iseven, 1:4)
```

if you want to see the source code for the method that would get dispatched. `@less` displays the source code using the system pager. `@edit` will open the file containing the method source code in a text editor. You can control which editor gets opened by setting the `JULIA_EDITOR` [environment variable](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/). For example, you can set your editor to **vim** by calling

```
ENV["JULIA_EDITOR"] = "vim"
```

either at the REPL or in your startup file, `~/.julia/config/startup.jl`. Alternatively, you can add `export JULIA_EDITOR=vim` to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file on linux/macos.

Comment: I'd also mention sister macros `@less` and `@edit` ;-)

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know about `@less`, that's awesome!